# mistake on db.session.delete() or validate_on_submit(), UPDATE: error in forms

Tags: database, forms, validation, flask, sqlalchemy

I couldn't delete a row from database, when I submit browser isn't responding, below there is part of the code

Here my code:

```
@app.route("/task/delete/<int:task_id>", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def DeleteTask(task_id):
    qry = db.session.query(Task).filter(Task.task_id == task_id)
    tsk = qry.first()
    if tsk:
        formpage = TaskForm(formdata=request.form, obj=tsk)
        print tsk
        if formpage.validate_on_submit():
            db.session.delete(tsk)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/task')
        return render_template('my_html.html', formpage=formpage)
```

my_db.py

```
Employee_Task = db.Table('employee_task',
                         db.Column('employee_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employee.employee_id')),
                         db.Column('task_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('task.task_id'))
                         )

class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)

class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_no = StringField('Task ID.:', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=10)])
    rel_task_employee = db.relationship("Employee", secondary=Employee_Task, backref="rel_employee_task")
```

my_form.py

```
class TaskForm(FlaskForm):
    task_no = StringField('Task ID.:', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=10)])
    task_name = StringField('Task Name:', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    submit = SubmitField('OK!')
```

my_html.html

```
<form method=post>
    <dl>
        {{ formpage.task_no }}
        {{ formpage.task_name }}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Delete>
</form>
```

`print tsk` shows correct data
However, when I `submit` browser is not responding.
Where is the mistake?

## UPDATE

I check for the validation error with

```
{% for error in formpage.errors %}
    <div>
        <p>ALERT!</p>
        {{ error }} INVALID
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and got following message

> Alert! task_no invalid
>   Alert! csrf_token invalid

It's strange,

1. Regarding `csrf_token invalid`, I solve by adding `{{ formpage.csrf_token }}`
   into html
2. Regarding `task_no invalid`, form is working very well during submit data in database, I'm using same form for delete that data.

any idea to solve point 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do your redirect without the slash as below ?

```py
return redirect('task')
```

Another way to do it would be by passing the `url_for()`  function to your redirect like this :

```py
return redirect(url_for('put_the_function_name_of_your_route_here'))
```

Comment: tried both without slash and with url_for(),     
no any response!

Comment: I update question, it seems error in the my_form.py. But, at the moment I don't know what's is exact mistake there...